# how to regain moisture into already made cold rolls/spring rolls

Tags: moisture

I made some cold rolls with carrot, cucumber, capsicum and chicken in rice paper rolls. we ate some yesterday but had some leftover. We put damp kitchen towel into the bottom of a container and one on the top of them. Now they are hard and chewy. I was wondering if there was a way to get the moisture back into the rolls.

Answer (score 2):

You can't regain the original texture in the rice paper once it's changed.  Spring rolls need to be eaten pretty much the same day they are made.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there's no way for you to regain the moisture in the any left over spring rolls especially after putting them in the fridge. Moisture from vegetable dries up very quickly even in room temperature let alone putting them in the fridges. Putting damp towel only helps to temporary soften the skin while they are in the fridge for a while but the inside of the vegetable still gets dried up. The best is still eating them freshly after they are being deep fried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dunking them in water, even pricking at the skin and letting sit wet for a while, and then heating them.  The heat lets things move, and combined with a very moist exterior will sometimes wick moisture inwards (into equilibrium).  Of course, sometimes you get hot, slimy, and still tough instead - its a possibility, not a certainty.